# Is there a Rails 4 circular dependent: :destroy workaround?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

As an example for the circular `dependent: :destroy` issue:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one: :staff, dependent: :destroy
end

class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
end
```

If I call `user.destroy`, the associated `staff` should be destroyed as well. Conversely, calling `staff.destroy` should destroy the associated `user` as well.

This worked great in Rails 3.x, but the behavior changed in Rails 4.0 (and continues in 4.1) such that a loop forms and eventually you get an error, "stack level too deep." One obvious workaround is to create a custom callback using `before_destroy` or `after_destroy` to manually destroy the associated objects instead of using the `dependent: :destroy` mechanism. Even the [issue in GitHub opened for this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13609) situation had a couple people recommending this workaround.

Unfortunately, I can't even get that workaround to work. This is what I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one: :staff

  after_destroy :destroy_staff

  def destroy_staff
    staff.destroy if staff and !staff.destroyed?
  end
end
```

The reason this doesn't work is that `staff.destroyed?` always returns `false`. So it forms a cycle.

Comment: did you implement that logic to both models as Jken13579 suggests?

Comment: @xlembouras, haven't tried it, but I'm pretty certain it won't work. I'll try it sometime this week just to be sure. I've written below why it won't work.

Comment: @at. any luck with my answer?

Answer (score 5):

If one side of the cycle only has that one callback, you can replace one of the `dependent: :destroy` with `dependent: :delete`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # delete prevents Staff's :destroy callback from happening
  has_one: :staff, dependent: :delete
  has_many :other_things, dependent: :destroy
end

class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base
  # use :destroy here so that other_things are properly removed
  belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Worked great for me, as long as one side doesn't need other callbacks to fire.

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue as well, and came up with a solution that isn't pretty but works. Essentially, you'd just use a `destroy_user` that's similar to `destroy_staff`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one: :staff

  after_destroy :destroy_staff

  def destroy_staff
    staff.destroy if staff && !staff.destroyed?
  end
end

class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  after_destroy :destroy_user

  def destroy_user
    user.destroy if user && !user.destroyed?
  end
end
```

Comment: Strange, stackoverflow didn't update my inbox that you had an answer. I'll try this, but I'm certain it won't work. I've tried so many variations. Essentially any `.destroyed?` call ***always*** returns false in Rails 4.1 if called from a `before_destroy` or `after_destroy` callback.

Comment: Hopefully it works for you in Rail 4.1, because I've only tested it in Rails 4.0, although I guess that shouldn't make a difference.