# Rails 4: stack level too deep when trying to destroy picture

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, paperclip

Hi I have a normal setup of Paperclip and S3 for image uploads in my application, this is the model I use for attachments:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :ofert, dependent: :destroy

    has_attached_file :image,   :styles => { :medium => "300x300#", :thumb => "100x100>", :large => "600x400#", :morethumb => "50x50#", :ultrathumb => "25x25#" },
                                :default_url => "https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/:s3_bucket/ofert_defaults/:style/brown_hat.jpg"

    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
    validates_attachment_presence :image, :if => :isProduction?
    validates_attachment_size :image, :less_than => 5.megabytes

    #process_in_background :image, processing_image_url: 'https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/:s3_bucket/ofert_defaults/:style/brown_hat.jpg'
end
```

The above works very well, however, when I try to destoy a picture:

```
picture.destroy
```

I get the following error: `stack level too deep`
but if instead I do the following:

```
picture.delete
```

It works, however the above only deletes the record but not the file uploaded to my S3 bucket, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in rails. Read [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13609)

Using

```
 belongs_to :ofert, dependent: :destroy
```

will cause a circular loop (assuming you have a similar line in the associated model 'Ofert' as well)
You can try replacing it with dependent :delete in one of these models or write after_destroy methods in both to manually destroy the associated model.
Read this discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208579/is-there-a-rails-4-circular-dependent-destroy-workaround) on stackoverflow